# Help.. in tigervnc, menu bars aren't shown in Gnome window

Tags: gnome, xfce, vnc

I was using tigervnc server just ok until an hour ago, then I tried to make the vnc server automatically start after boot(because I had to start it with "vncserver -localhost no :2 -geometry 3840x2160"), and failed it. I doesn't start automatically, but now, when I start the server manually, the gnome windows doesn't show any menu at the left side. But I can access the control menu from the top right menu button(arrow). How should I fix it?
In the meantime, I had installed xfce4 and (selected gdm instead of lightdm) and later apt removed xfce4.
ADD : I found a small menu reading `Activities` on the top left and when I click it, I see the usual menu bar appear. So I want the menus appear by default (without the `Activities` menu) and also want the right mouse click pull-down menu to show terminal (which it doesn't now).

Comment: I don't know about your issue, but you could use `vino-server`, the default VNC server. Simply run `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server`.

Comment: yeah, I am aware of vino, but that's not what I want. thanks anyway.